# Template is Missing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I am trying to run a simple blog post at `localhost:3000/posts`.

When I try to access the page, I receive this error.

```
Template is missing

Missing template posts/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views"
```

Here is a copy of the code in my `posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
end
```

I have the `index.html.erb` file in my `c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views` directory, so I am not sure why this is happening.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to resolve this issue?

Comment: One thing to note; if for some reason you needed to change your posts controller directory name, you will need to recreate all of your views for that controller, even if the views directory name currently matches the controller. Just something I had a problem with and worked through by recreating.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `index.html.erb` inside the `posts` folder at `rubyblog/app/views/posts`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html.erb` file should be in `c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views/posts`.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your view code in its respective folder.

In your case you should place `index.html.erb` into `c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views/posts/` folder

Template is missing error arises when it doesn't able to locate the view file.